# Integrate Piwik Analytics into SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint, matomo

What is a clean method to integrate Piwik 3.0.2 analytics into an SharePoint 2016 on-premise farm? Piwik itself suggests to embedd the following snippet into the head-section of a webpage. How to achieve this for all of our ~5000 site collections in a clean and support way? Thanks for your help :)

```html
<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//my-piwik-url/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', '3']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an add-in frastructure in your farm you could also have a look at the [Web Analytics Integration add-in](https://store.office.com/en-001/app.aspx?assetid=WA103045499)

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would make a scriptlink custom action and point it to a file I host (in sharepoint or otherwise). You could rig up some powershell to loop through your tenant and install the custom action to each site collection. Check out [this write up on how to accomplish this with powershell](http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2016/01/add-custom-javascript-file-to-all-pages.html)

Comment: Keep in mind that simply adding a script block as above will probably not (always) work, if MDS is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution to demonstate a simple piwik-integration in SharePoint at https://github.com/nils-a/piwik4sp.

It will work even if [MDS (minimal download strategy)](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/minimal-download-strategy-overview) is active. However, it's a sandbox solution and as you said you have ~5000 site collections you should modify to have only one instance of the files (i.e. Use a farm-solution or a dedicated site if farm-solution is not an option.)

When you never (**never, ever**) have MDS enabled an action like the following should do the trick:

```
<CustomAction Id="Piwik4SP.Script.Link"
    Location="ScriptLink"
    Sequence="202"
    ScriptBlock="var _paq = _paq || [];
      /* tracker methods like 'setCustomDimension' should be called before 'trackPageView' */
      _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
      _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
      (function() {
        var u='//my-piwik-url/';
        _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
        _paq.push(['setSiteId', '3']);
        var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
      })();" />
```

However, to integrate nicely (even with MDS) use a scriptLink to deploy your js-file [like this](https://github.com/nils-a/piwik4sp/blob/master/src/Piwik4SP/Piwik4SP/ScriptRegistration/Elements.xml):

```
<CustomAction Id="Piwik.Script.Link"
    Location="ScriptLink"
    Sequence="202"
    ScriptSrc="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/Piwik4SP/piwik.js" />
```

in "your" piwik.js ensure you are registering a module for MDS:

```
window.RegisterModuleInit('/path/to/your/piwik.js', someFuncToCallOnNavigate);
```

in `someFuncToCallOnNavigate` you should then check, if piwik.js is already loaded and load if needed. After that you can start tracking as documented in the piwik api. Be aware, though that - if MDS is enabled - most of your page-requests will be to `start.aspx`. So you'll probably want to to modify the url before tracking it. See [this file](https://github.com/nils-a/piwik4sp/blob/master/src/Piwik4SP/Piwik4SP/SiteAssets/Piwik4SP/piwik.js) on how I tried to solve that problem.